# react.js GitHUb Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github

I'm new to this part,

What I'm trying to do is a Create React.JS website with Firebase Hosting
I have done a test site using VS Code, where I manage to deploy without any issues.

If I'm going to include GitHub into a project how do I do it?
I'm not sure, but think below is the correct order?

1. Create Git Repo
2. Clone it into the computer
3. Create react project
4. Create Firebase project

Comment: just create a repo on github , there you will get all the instructions how to add your project with repo, Create react app then on that app do git init to initialize github do git add origin _______ whatever origin you have got from github check newly created repo and similarly follow those instructions no need to clone that empty repo

Answer (score 0):

At any time you can link Git to your project, for that you can do:

1. Create git repository
2. Add origin with the code:

   git remote add origin https://github.com/USER/YOUR_REPOSITORY_LINK.git
3. Commit your changes and push.

I would create react project first, than add git with the steps above.